# Use an angular directive to activate or deactivate a call to a service

Tags: angularjs

I'm checking whether or not a username already exists when I create a new user. I also want to be able to edit a user, and I'm actually using the same form for this. When the form is in edit-mode, you are not allowed to change the username and the input field will be disabled.

I have a directive that checks with the database if the username is unique, and validates or invalidates the input. This directive should not fire when the form is in edit-mode, because the username is not allowed to be edited, and the form should validate.

```
<input name="alias" 
    class="form-control" 
    type="text" 
    ng-model="user.alias" 
    required
    ng-model-options="{ debounce: { default : 500, blur: 0 }}" 
    validate-alias="{{formMode == 'new' ? true : false}}" 
    />
```

And the directive:

```
.directive('validateAlias', function($http, $q) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            validateAlias: '=',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
                attrs.$observe('validateAlias', function(){
                    console.log("validateAlias: " + attrs.validateAlias + ", which is a " + typeof attrs.validateAlias);
                    //this returns "validateAlias: false, which is a string"

                    if (attrs.validateAlias === 'true') console.log("should work"); else console.log("n/a");
                    //this returns "should work"    

                    if (attrs.validateAlias === 'true') {
                        ngModel.$asyncValidators.username = function (alias) {
                            return $http.get(aliasurl + alias).then(
                                function (response) {
                                    if (response.data.length > 0) {
                                        return $q.reject('Username not unique');
                                    } else {
                                        return $q.resolve();
                                    }
                                }
                            );
                        };
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    })
```

So what happens is that in the edit-mode the first if-statement returns what I expect (false, aka do not validate, and the attribute in the DOM matches this, displaying validate-alias='false'), yet the username is still checked with the database. 
Everything works fine when I'm in new-mode, but that's probably just coincidence, not because the code works as it should.

I am doing something wrong, but I can't figure out where...!

---

### Edit:

Right, I've changed things around a little bit. I now have the following directive:

```
.directive('validateAlias', function($http, $q) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                validateAlias: '@'
            },
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.$watch(attrs.validateAlias, function(v){
                    console.log("validateAlias: " + v + ", which is a " + typeof v);
                    if (v === true) console.log("the check is active"); else console.log("the check is NOT active");
                    if (v === true) {
                        ngModel.$asyncValidators.username = function (alias) {
                            return $http.get(aliasurl + alias).then(
                                function (response) {
                                    if (response.data.length > 0) {
                                        return $q.reject('Username not unique');
                                    } else {
                                        return $q.resolve();
                                    }
                                }
                            );
                        };
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    })
```

Now the $watch does not seem to work... what am I missing?

---

### Final edit:

The DOM had a set variable "false" for the attribute I made... the watch worked fine, but the DOM was generated once, so there was nothing to watch.

Luckily for me, every time the attribute changed, I could reload the DOM as well (virtually switching screens), and so the scope reads the attribute again, and the variable is passed, making the directive do exactly what I want. The code I posted after the first edit is what I used.

I'm not sure if that's the Angular way, but it works for now. When I find a better solution, I'll update the code.

Comment: isn't you should comapre attrs.validateAlias.value === true instead of attrs.validateAlias.value === 'true'

Comment: That's what I thought too, but the boolean is (apparently) passed as a string.

Comment: I think you should use `$watch` and declare `validateAlias` in scope.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
.directive('validateAlias', function($http, $q) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            scope: {
               validateAlias: '=',
            }
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
                scope.$watch('validateAlias', function(watchData){
                    console.log("validateAlias: " + watchData + ", which is a " + typeof watchData);

                    if (watchData === 'true') console.log("should work"); else console.log("n/a");
                    //this returns "should work"    

                    if (watchData.value === 'true') {
                        ngModel.$asyncValidators.username = function (alias) {
                            return $http.get(aliasurl + alias).then(
                                function (response) {
                                    if (response.data.length > 0) {
                                        return $q.reject('Username not unique');
                                    } else {
                                        return $q.resolve();
                                    }
                                }
                            );
                        };
                    }
                });
            }
        };
})
```

Comment: Setting the variable globally makes it impossible to have a conditional statement in my input attribute. (angular falls over the inline {{'s in validate-alias="{{formMode == 'new' ? true : false}}").

Comment: If you have some suggested edits in my answer then update the answer, so it will be correct one for your question.